# Bootstrap Basics

Tags: inference, bootstrap

When using random sampling (bootstrap), I get 3500 estimates of R squared. Curious as to what causes the variation between these individual estimates as they've all been pulled from the same dataset. Just trying to expand my understanding, thanks!

Comment: Could you make your question more specific? If you take random samples, they would obviously be different at random, so would lead to different results, but I guess you wouldn't be asking about that?

Comment: The bootstrap simply samples *with* replacement from the original dataset, it is a natural emulation of frequentist variability. Consider if I flipped a coin two times and obtain {H, T}. In that case, my bootstrap resamples can be (with equal probability) {H,T}, {H,H}, {T,H}, {T,T}. I estimate the proportion of heads the same in each dataset,

Comment: [We have many posts explaining this.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=bootstrap%20intuit*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

While you’re drawing from the same dataset, each bootstrap sample is different. Consequently, calculations based on individual bootstrap samples should not be expected to be the same.

Consider an easy dataset of $D=(1, 2, 3)$. Let’s bootstrap and calculate the mean, $\bar x$.

$$
D_{boot1}=(1,3,1)\implies \bar x_{boot1}=5/3\\
D_{boot2}=(1,1,2)\implies\bar x_{boot2}=4/3
$$

Et cetera…

**EDIT**

Let's do an example for $R^2$. Consider a dataset $D$.

$$
D = ((1,2), (2,2), (3, 5), (4, 3))\\
D_{boot1} = ((1,2), (1,2), (3,5), (2, 2)) \implies R^2_{boot1} = 0.758\\
D_{boot2} = ((1,2), (3,5), (3,5), (4,3)) \implies R^2_{boot1} = 0.236
$$

However, in the original $D$, $R^2=0.3$.

Comment: Thanks! So, the variation between the estimates lies in the mean which would create the variation between R squared values.